On each box of a chessboard we write a number. Fields are congruent $\iff$ same number is on them. Variance of pairs of congruent fields.
On each box of a $3 \times 3$ chessboard is written at random one of the numbers $1, 2, . . ., 6$ (the choices corresponding to different fields are independent, each number has the same $\frac{1}{6}$ chance of being chosen). Two fields bordering a side will be called congruent if the same number is on them. Determine the expected value and variance of the number of pairs of congruent fields.

There are two types of congruent pairs on the chessboard: horizontal pairs and vertical pairs. On a $3 \times 3$ chessboard, there are $3 \cdot 2 = 6$ horizontal pairs and $2 \cdot 3 = 6$ vertical pairs. Hence, there are a total of $12$ pairs of adjacent fields.
Let $X_{ij}$​ be the indicator variable that is $1$ if the pair $(i,j)$ of fields are congruent and $0$ otherwise. The total number of congruent pairs $X$ is the sum of these indicator variables:
$$X = \sum_{(i,j) \in \text{pairs}} ​X_{ij}​$$
The probability that a given pair of adjacent fields is congruent is: $\mathbb{P}(X_{ij}​=1) = \frac{1}{6}​$ because each field independently takes one of six values, and there is a $\frac{6}{36} = \frac{1}{6}$​ chance that two fields are the same.
Since $X_{ij}$​ is an indicator variable: $\mathbb{E}[X_{i,j}​] = \mathbb{P}(X_{i,j​}=1) = \frac{1}{6}$​
By the linearity of expectation:
$$\mathbb{E}[X]= \mathbb{E} \sum_{(i,j) \in pairs} X_{i,j}​ ​= \sum_{(i,j) \in pairs}​ \mathbb{E}[X_{i,j}​] = 12 \cdot \frac{1}{6} = 2$$
I hope that it is correct.
However, I don't know how to do the variance. I suppose that it would be necessary to think about adjacent pairs that share a common field (they are in some way dependent on each other) and non-adjacent pairs (those would be independent). If anybody has an idea, sharing it would be much appreciated.

Your indicator functions $X_{i,j}$ are pairwise independent (but not just independent,as quadruples of them are dependent if they form a $2\times 2$ square). This implies their covariances are all zero and hence the variance of the sum is the sum of variances, i.e
$$
Var(X)=\sum Var(X_{i,j})=12\ Var (X_{i,j})=12\times \frac16\times \frac56.
$$

Why are indicator functions $X_{ij}$ pairwise independent? Let's say that 2 indicator functions contain the same filed. Then if some number if written in that field it will influence the pairs, isn't that true? Let's say that we have $4$ fields, $2$ of them on one side of chessboard and $2$ of them on the other. Then for them to be $2$ pairs of congruent fields we have $6 \cdot 6$ possibilities (one of $6$ for first pair and one of $6$ for other pair). On the other hand when $2$ pairs of fields share the same field, we have only $6$ possibilities for them to create $2$ congruent pairs.

Indeed, assume that $X$ and $X'$ are indicators which are based on three squares (that is they share a common square). An easy calculation gives that $P(X=1,X'=1)=\frac6{6^3}=\frac1{36}$ which incidentally equals the product of $P(X=1)$ and $P(X'=1)$ so they are independent.
